# Equivalent of ImageView.setColorFilter() for a drawable?

Tags: android

In the ImageView class there's a method for applying a tint, "setColorFilter":

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setColorFilter(int](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setColorFilter%28int), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode)

I'm wondering if there's a way to achieve the same thing with a drawable? For example, the actionbar menu items want a drawable resource for an icon. Is there a way to use a LayerDrawable for example to achieve the same thing?

I have many color variations for a particular drawable and don't want to have to generate all the possible variations as pngs to ship with the app.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the identically named [`setColorFilter()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#setColorFilter%28android.graphics.ColorFilter%29) method on the `Drawable` class.

Simply call `myDrawable.setColorFilter(filter)`.